# Praising someone for noticing something

Tags: idioms, phrases

I would like ask for phrases/idioms that can be used to praise someone (especially children) for spotting small things that would otherwise go unnoticed.

I know that 'well spotted' is a common one, and 'good catch' can be used when mistakes are identified. Are there any others that have similar meanings?

Many thanks.

Comment: How about calling the person "eagle eyes"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Well spotted!" sound very British to me, but I find myself using it all the time as British expressions creep into American speech especially after "Harry Potter".  For example, nowadays, (or perhaps just now, *today*) I often wish people "Happy Christmas!".

"Good catch" feels more American.

When Americans (not sure about British) want to praise someone who has seen something others haven't:

> "You've got good eyes!" (or just "Good eyes!")
>
> "Sharp eyes you've got!"
>
> "You've got 20/20 vision there!" (less common, but acceptable)

Other more generic phrases:

> "Well done!"
>
> "Well done you!" (although this can be perceived as sarcastic)
>
> "Good one!"
>
> "Good on yer!" (very, very Australian)
>
> (On getting a question right, or knowing something) (British) "Full marks!"  (American) "You get a gold star!"

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking  more for phrases that directly refer to 'spotting' something. I feel like 'well done' or 'Good one' seem a bit too general.

Comment: @JUNCINATOR  yes I was hoping to think of some by association with similar phrases.  I did think of one, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Variations of "good/great find!" used with a tone of exclamation can be well suited as a compliment when someone, especially a child, makes an unexpected and valuable discovery of detail.